# Is there any option in order to get more than 10 twitter trending topics with twitter4j?

Tags: java, spring-boot, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to get hashtags more used on Twitter. In fact, I am using twitter4j library as shown below:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
Trends trends = twitter.getPlaceTrends(1);
for (int i = 0; i < trends.getTrends().length; i++) {
    if(trends.getTrends()[i].getName().startsWith("#")) {
        System.out.println(trends.getTrends()[i].getName());
    }
}
```

The problem is that getPlaceTrends() returns 10 trending topics and I need more than 10 (need 100 trending topics).

Is there some way in order to get 100 trending topics ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Twitter4j just wraps Twitter's `trends/place` API endpoint, which returns **up to 50** trending topics for a specific id. There is no parameter on Twitter's end to set the number of topics returned, so it's not possible ([1](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place)).